# PowerPoint VBA code to bring focus back to the running PowerPoint Slideshow

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint Presentation with embedded word document. I have a macro button on the presentation which opens the  embedded word document, changes some stuff in in, and saves it (word) as PDF document. But as soon as everything is done, the user is shown the powerpoint slides mode while presentation(slideshow) is still running in background. How can I bring the focus back to the running slideshow? The macro is supposed to run in slideshow mode.

Below is my code

```
Private Sub Gen_Click()
    ' I am changing the presentation to normal view, in order to execute DoVerb thing!
    ActivePresentation.Windows(1).Activate

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(1)

        If .Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then

            For Each sVerb In .OLEFormat.ObjectVerbs

                nCount = nCount + 1

                If sVerb = "Open" Then

                    .OLEFormat.DoVerb nCount

                    Exit For

                End If

            Next

        End If

    End With

    'switch back to slide show view
    SlideShowWindows(1).Activate

'getting opened word document object to do stuff in in
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument
objWord.Visible = False

'Doing stuff here

'closing the word doc
objDoc.Saved = True
objWord.Quit

End Sub
```

This code is making power point to return to normal mode with button to Resume slideshow!

Comment: Have you tried moving the "SlideShowWindows(1).Activate" line to the end, just before End Sub?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Yes I did tried that! It works very well if I us F8 for step-in for executing one by one! but fails when actual slideshow is running! I also tried sending %TAB to switch, %n to  minimize, using SendKeys, but those are not working either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working using CommandBar controls to switchback to the slideshow mode!

added following code before End Sub

```
Call CommandBars.FindControl(Id:=740).Execute
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox strErrorMessage
        Err.Clear
    End If
```

- 740 is the id for running slideshow from the ribbon menu!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works as well and is even simpler:

```
' change focus to power point 
AppActivate (ActivePresentation.Name)
```